# Deletion of two separate interdependent models

Tags: angular

I have 2 user and contact models
I have no connection between the tables I want as soon as the user is deleted then the same contactName created with it will also be deleted

for exmaple:
[image]

What I do in SignUp adds both a new Contact and a new User but
In deletion I do not know how to catch them because they are not connected to each other.

Add work good (add the contact and the user together):

```
signUp(){
    this.usersService.Register(this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe(() => {
    this.contactsService.AddContact(this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.swal.success();
      this.signupForm.reset();
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
    },(e)=> {
      this.errorsService.errors(e);
    })
  }
```

Delete: (not work):

```
this.contactsService.DeleteContact(contact.id)
    .subscribe(() =>{
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })

    this.usersService.DeleteUser(user.id)
    .subscribe(()=>{
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      })
    }
```

In the deletion he only deletes the user and not the contact because the navigation is done according to the user's id

Comment: You should add in the contact model a field 'userId' indexable, so whenever you delete with user, you could as well find the info to delete the contact.

Comment: That's the problem I can't do this,The models are not supposed to know each other

Comment: Why ? 
If so, can't you save both info in another model, and use that instead ?

Comment: Because it's micro service

Comment: I see but this doesn't explain why you can't' have a 'userId' field inside the Contact model, would you mind sharing more or explain more here ? Otherwise as mentioned, you could just chain in a certain way to create your contact ( first create User, wait for response, then create contact )

Comment: If on the server there is no connection between the models then in the client can I make the connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246346/discussion-between-ziyed-and-nadav-pall).

Answer (score 0):

You should add in the contact model a field 'userId' indexable, so whenever you delete with user, you could as well find the info to delete the contact.

```
Contact {
   userId: string // This relates to the user.id you get
}
```

This also means you should save contact, after you got user saved ( to use that id, for the db relation )

```
this.usersService.Register(this.signupForm.value).subscribe(
   (user: any) => {
      this.contactsService.AddContact(this.signupForm.value, { userId: user.id })
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.swal.success();
          this.signupForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        })
    },(e)=> {
      this.errorsService.errors(e);
    })
```